# Working with duplicated nested SVG elements

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I came across following problem while working with `snap.svg`.

I would like to use nested SVG elements inside a main one. Let's say one of this nested one has a structure like this:

```
<svg width="71" height="101" viewBox="0 0 71 101">
<defs>
    <rect id="a" width="70" height="100" rx="5"/>
    <mask id="d" width="70" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="#fff">
    <use xlink:href="#a"/>
    </mask>
    <rect id="b" width="70" height="100" rx="5"/>
    <mask id="e" width="70" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="#fff">
    <use xlink:href="#b"/>
    </mask>
    <pattern id="f" width="6" height="5" x="-6" y="-5" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <use transform="scale(.5)" xlink:href="#tipstercard-c"/>
    </pattern>
    <image id="c" width="12" height="10" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..."/>
</defs>
<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(.338 .194)">
    <use fill="#212120" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#tipstercard-d)" xlink:href="#a"/>
    <use fill="url(#f)" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#e)" style="mix-blend-mode:luminosity" xlink:href="#b"/>
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M20.22 47.784v1.53h-1.344v2.923c0 .593.013.937.04 1.035a.42.42 0 0 0 .174.241c.091.064.2>...
```

I tried to do sth like `fragments['card'].select('svg').clone();`, but this results in: `TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

I tried also following `fragments['card'].select('svg').toDefs();`, but this results in: `DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.`

What would be a possible way to do it with snap?

**EDIT**
Seems like I needed to use:

```
  Surface.append(fragments['card']);
  const Card = Surface.select('#card');
  Card.toDefs();
  const CardDef = Surface.select('#card');
  CardDef.use().attr({...});
```

Now the question is why this doesn't work `fragments['card'].select('svg').toDefs();` and the above code does? Why cannot I use `fragments['card'].select('svg')` directly?

Comment: What is fragments['card'] ? Without that code it's tricky. Assuming it is actually a fragment, that wouldn't have any methods like clone() (basically it has select/selectAll/setAttribute etc, no Snap methods).

Comment: @Ian fragments['card'] is a fragment. When trying to invoke `<AFragment>.select('svg').clone();` I'm getting `TypeError` mentioned above. I can also share the actual SVG if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fragment has no notion of Snap methods, so methods like clone() will not work. First they need to be appended to the DOM. Also a fragment isn't fully in the DOM, so there are issues with some common svg methods that would be available to DOM SVG elements.

So something like fragment.select('svg').clone() wouldn't work (as clone is a Snap method). First you need to 'Snapify' it (turn it into a Snap element, a wrapper around the svg element).

So you would need to do something like the following..first add it to the DOM...

```
Surface.append( fragment.select('svg') );
```

Now that its in the DOM, you can Snapify it and clone it (as we now have the Snap methods available to this element).

```
Surface.select('someId').clone();
```

Note, if you have a DOM element somewhere, you can also turn it into a Snap element, by doing

```
var snapElement = Snap( someDomElement );
```

This keeps the DOM element as it is, but just adds a Snap wrapper around it, and returns this as the Snap element.

So you found the right code yourself, and the main answer is that your element wasn't a Snap element when trying to call methods on it (or appended to the DOM).

Note: You can kind of Snapify a fragment without adding it to the DOM, but it doesn't bring you any new methods unless it's in the main DOM I think, but could be handy for just storing a reference to an element that will get appended later.